# Unable to update the tls-cipher-suites for node exporter in openshift 3.11

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, okd, nessus

Im trying to update the `tls-cipher-suites` for the `daemonset.apps/node-exporter` of `openshift-monitoring` namespace using `oc edit daemonset.apps/node-exporter -n openshift-monitoring`

```
.
.
.
      - args:
        - --secure-listen-address=:9100
        - --upstream=http://127.0.0.1:9101/
        - --tls-cert-file=/etc/tls/private/tls.crt
        - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/tls/private/tls.key
        - --tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        image: quay.io/coreos/kube-rbac-proxy:v0.3.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kube-rbac-proxy
        ports:
.
.
.
```

Once the `tls-cipher-suites` are updated, i see that node-exporter pods are getting re-deployed. But when I check the `daemonset.apps/node-exporter` using `oc get -o yaml daemonset.apps/node-exporter -n openshift-monitoring` i see that the updates done to `tls-cipher-suites` are lost and it has got re-set to old value.
How can i set this value permanently?

Note: The purpose of updating `tls-cipher-suites` is Nessus scan has reported `SWEET32` vulnerability for port 9100 for the Medium Strength Ciphers: ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA and DES-CBC3-SHA.

Comment: Did you try deleting the daemonset, correcting the yaml and deploying it again? Without live editing?

Comment: I have tried now, but observed that daemonset gets re-created automatically, after deletion.

Comment: Did you mean pod? Pod gets recreated? Because it doesn't make sens. Daemonset should not get recreated when deleted. Are you using some kind of custom controller?

Comment: Daemonset is getting re-created, thats really weird behavior. I'm not using any custom controller. I have installed the okd 3.11 using https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/tree/release-3.11. Not sure if this set-ups some functionality due to which we are seeing this behavior.

Comment: how did you install the node-exporter?

Comment: node-exporter gets installed with okd 3.11 installation using above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openshift 3.11 seems to indeed be using [openshift_cluster_monitoring_operator](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/tree/release-3.11/roles/openshift_cluster_monitoring_operator). This is why when you delete or change anything it recovers it to its defaults.

It manages node-exporter installation and it doesn't seem to allow for customizing node-exporter installation. Take a look at [the cluster-monitoring-operator docs](https://github.com/openshift/cluster-monitoring-operator/blob/ca646cfdb92b202289c3faf92227fcaddd19c8a1/Documentation/user-guides/configuring-cluster-monitoring.md#nodeexporterconfig)

My recommendation would be to [uninstall openshift monitoring operator](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/tree/release-3.11/roles/openshift_cluster_monitoring_operator#installation) and install node-exporter yourself from [official node-exporter repository](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/master/manifests/node-exporter-daemonset.yaml) or with [helm chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts) where you actually have full controll over deployment.